# MahApps Show SimpleChildWindow using MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, mahapps.metro

Is there any way to display a simple child window in MahApps, how do we display dialogs (using DialogCoordinator)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at this time, use this:

```
  private async void show()
        {
            await ((MahApps.Metro.Controls.MetroWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).ShowChildWindowAsync(new SampleChildWindow());
        }
```